# PHP stdClass Object - foreach

Tags: php, arrays, api, object

I'm using an API to get domain DNS details. The results printed show like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [test.co.uk] => stdClass Object
        (
            [records] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [mname] => ns1.test.com.
                            [rname] => hostmaster.test.com.
                            [serial] => 12345678
                            [refresh] => 1800
                            [retry] => 900
                            [expire] => 1209600
                            [minimum-ttl] => 300
                            [ref] => 
                            [host] => test.co.uk
                            [type] => SOA
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [target] => ns1.test.com
                            [ref] => 
                            [host] => test.co.uk
                            [type] => NS
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [target] => ns2.test.com
                            [ref] => 
                            [host] => test.co.uk
                            [type] => NS
                        )
```

How can I turn each of the records ([0], [1], [2] etc) into variables? I am wanting to show them in a table

I have tried the below, but no result is shown

```
$Test=$PackageDNSInfo->test.co.uk->records[0]->mname; 
echo $Test;
```

Comment: Use curly braces: `$PackageDNSInfo->{'test.co.uk'}->records[0]->mname; `

Comment: @Jeto - thanks, is there a way to do a 'foreach' to display them all in a table?

Comment: Yes, you can `foreach` on a stdClass object if you'd like (key will be the property name, value will be its value).

Comment: @Jeto - Are you able to provide an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `foreach` on it, just like you would on an array:

```
foreach ($PackageDNSInfo as $url => $data) {
    foreach ($data->records as $record) {
        $type = $record->type;
        $host = $record->host;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

If you want to access a given URL's data directly, use curly braces:

```
echo $PackageDNSInfo->{'test.co.uk'}->records[0]->mname;
```

Comment: Thanks but I am wanting a foreach for each of the records, so i can display them in a table. something like `$Type=$PackageDNSInfo->{"$RelDomIDName"}->records[5]->type; 
$Host=$PackageDNSInfo->{"$RelDomIDName"}->records[5]->host;
$Ref=$PackageDNSInfo->{"$RelDomIDName"}->records[5]->ref;
$IP=$PackageDNSInfo->{"$RelDomIDName"}->records[5]->ip;`

Comment: Okay so doing this, seems to show nothing when i echo.... `foreach ($PackageDNSInfo as $url => $data) {
    foreach ($data['records'] as $record) {
        $type = $record->type;
        $host = $record->host;
        echo"$type";
    }}`

Comment: Can we continue in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222492/room-for-designer-and-jeto

Comment: Had a typo in there (`$data['records']` should've been `$data->records`), should be better now.